# Java Columns and Rows

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, header

Java Help.

> Write a program that prints the seating chart on the screen and
>   prompts the user to pick either a seat or a price. Mark sold seats by
>   changing the price to 0(zero). When a user specifies a seat, make sure
>   it is available. If it is not available, inform the user and prompt
>   them  to pick either a seat or a price.

The teacher wants the rows to be A-I and the columns to be 1-10 i cannot get this because i didn't learn this advanced java at my liberal arts school. The teacher also wants it to output Stage which i cannot get it to do.

```
public class TheatreSeating {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 


        // Two dimensional array to hold seats
        int[10][9] seatsArray = 
                 {{ 30, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 40, 30 },
                { 20, 30, 30, 40, 50, 50, 40, 30, 30, 20 },
                { 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 30, 30, 20, 20 },
                { 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10 },
                { 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10 },
                { 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10 },
                { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 },
                { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 },
                { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 }};
       String continueFlag = "Y";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (continueFlag.equals("Y") || continueFlag.equals("y")) {
            System.out.println("Please Select an option");
            System.out.println("1. Select Seat");
            System.out.println("2. Select Price");

            // Get selected option
            int option = input.nextInt();
            if (option == 1) {
                System.out
                        .println("Please enter the row number of seat (1-10):");
                // Subtract 1 as array starts from 0
                char row = input.nextInt() - 1;
                System.out
                        .println("Please enter the column number of seat (1-10):");
                // Subtract 1 as array starts from 0
                int column = input.nextInt() - 1;
                boolean seatAvailable = isSeatAvailable(seatsArray, row, column);
                if (seatAvailable) {
                    // Assign Seat
                    seatsArray[row][column] = 0;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Requested seat is not available");
                }
            } else if (option == 2) {
                System.out
                        .println("Please enter the Price(10,20,30,40 or 50):");
                int price = input.nextInt();
                // Check available seat
                boolean found = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < seatsArray.length; i++) {
                    // Continue looking only if not found
                    if (found == false) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < seatsArray[i].length; j++) {
                            if (seatsArray[i][j] == price) {
                                // Assign the seat
                                seatsArray[i][j] = 0;
                                found = true;
                                // Exit from inner loop
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            printSeats(seatsArray);
            System.out.println("Do you want to enter more seats (Y/N)");
            continueFlag = input.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Bye");
    }

    private static void printSeats(int[][] seatsArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < seatsArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < seatsArray[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(seatsArray[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static boolean isSeatAvailable(int[][] seatsArray, int row,
            int column) {
        for (int i = 0; i < seatsArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < seatsArray[i].length; j++) {
                if (i == row && j == column && seatsArray[i][j] != 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does it even compile?

Comment: It compiles I am just having a hard time coming up with the code to make there be rows (A-I) and column (1-10) appear ive tried everything and it keeps messing up when i try to put in my code. I also have to have it output the word stage at the top.

Comment: `int[10][9] seatsArray = .....;` compiles?

Comment: wait no that doesnt compile

Comment: also char row = input.nextInt() - 1; doesnt compile i had the characters in there at first but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify the array size when you define the reference.

```
int[10][9] twoDArray; // ERROR!
```

You specify the size when you allocate the memory using the `new` keyword as

```
int[][] twoDArray = new int[10][9];
```

But, since you're initializing directly you don't need to specify the size anywhere.

```
int[][] twoDArray = { {0,0}, {1,1} }; // same as
int[][] twoDArray = new int[][] { {0,0}, {1,1} }; // but
int[][] twoDArray = new int[10][9] { {0,0}, {1,1} }; // ERROR!
```

You also can't assign an `int` expression directly to a `char`. You need an explicit cast `()` there to let the compiler know that you understand that you could lose some precision there since you're stuffing an `int`, a bigger data type, into the smaller `char` data type.

```
char row = (char) (input.nextInt() - 1);
```

But, you shouldn't be using a `char` there at all. Change it to `int` like you have for your `column`.

```
int row = input.nextInt() - 1;
```

Comment: I get an error when  i put the -1 on char row = (char) input.nextInt() - 1;

Comment: how could i get it not to lose precision if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Ah, it should be `char row = (char) (input.nextInt() - 1);` Notice the parentheses. Otherwise the `int` returned from `nextInt()` becomes a `char` but when you subtract 1 it becomes an `int` again.

Comment: It's best if you use an `int row` just like `int column`.

Comment: Sorry to bug you but i had another question how would i go about bolding and spacing this string System.out.println("Stage"). I fixed what you told me now I just need to bold this and put rows in columns into the assignment.

Comment: You can have it spaced out by adding the required number of spaces in the string itself like `System.out.println(" Stage ")` but you won't be able to bold out the text since you're printing it out a console. On the console there's no concept like bold, italics etc. That happens within documents only.

Comment: I have another question how might I get a person to input the characters (A-I) with the coding i have every time I input the character i get an error.